# raise UnidentifiedImageError( PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000018CA596D350>

Tags: python, image, io, encode, bytesio

I'm getting the error 'raise UnidentifiedImageError(
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000018CA596D350>' in the following code:

```
import io
from PIL import Image 

file = io.BytesIO(str.encode('D:/Downloads/imagens/0b4d4db99a7b8ecba24909d277556de8.png'))

img1=Image.open(file)
img1.show()
```

There's much other questions like this, but none of them seem to be the same problem. If I take the 'str.encode' off the error goes to "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to open that file?

```py
img1 = Image.open('D:/Downloads/imagens/0b4d4db99a7b8ecba24909d277556de8.png')

# or
with open('D:/Downloads/imagens/0b4d4db99a7b8ecba24909d277556de8.png', 'rb') as fh:
    img1 = Image.open(fh)
```

[Docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#image-module) for reference:

> This is a lazy operation; this function identifies the file, but the file remains open and the actual image data is not read from the file until you try to process the data (or call the load() method). See new(). See File Handling in Pillow.

> Parameters

> `fp` – A filename (string), pathlib.Path object or a file object. The file object must implement file.read, file.seek, and file.tell methods, and be opened in binary mode.

Comment: If I need to make the same thing with a MySQL image, how can I avoid the same error? (Your solution worked)

Comment: A MySQL image? like a BLOB? That would be when you'd use a `BytesIO` object. You'd feed the blob into the bytesIO and give that to `Image.open`

Comment: That's what I don't understand, it's not a BLOB, it's "type: IMG", and brings the same problem on my question

Comment: I think you'll need to update your question, because I'm not quite sure what you mean

Comment: That's ok, ty for your help in this one